# How can I create a column of dummy variables ranging from 1-4 based on another column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataset on vehicles, I am hoping to create a new column in my data frame which takes on the values of 1 to 4: fuel_type = dummy (1,2,3,4) for ('Diesel', 'Petrol', 'LPG', 'CNG'), the following are my lines of thinking in regards to this, although I am not sure how to make it work.
fuel is another column containing the categorical names = ('Diesel', 'Petrol', 'LPG', 'CNG')

```
def fuel():
    if df['fuel'] =='Diesel':
            return 1
    elif df['fuel'] =='Petrol':
            return 2
    elif df['fuel'] =='LPG':
            return 3
    elif df['fuel'] =='CNG':
            return 4
```

or alternatively

```
df['fuel_type'] = df.fuel.apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='Diesel' else
(2 if 'Petrol' else
(3 if 'LPG' else
(4 if 'CNG'))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a dictionary `d` and map it with `map`:

```
d = {'Diesel': 1, 'Petrol': 2, 'LPG': 3, 'CNG': 4}
df['fuel_type'] = df['fuel'].map(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try

```
     import numpy as np
condition=[df['fuel'] =='Diesel',df['fuel'] =='Petrol',\
           df['fuel'] =='LPG',df['fuel'] =='CNG']
Choices=[1,2,3,4]
df['fuel_type']=np.select(condition, choices)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

You're almost there, just need to make a couple minor changes to your existing code. You can use a predefined function *inside* your lambda function. First, however, you need to change your `fuel()` function to accept an argument, like so:

```
def fuel(x):
    if x =='Diesel':
            return 1
    elif x =='Petrol':
            return 2
    elif x =='LPG':
            return 3
    elif x =='CNG':
            return 4
```

Now you can use `apply()` to apply this function to each item in the `fuel` column and create the new values for your `fuel_type` column:

```
df['fuel_type'] = df.fuel.apply(lambda x:fuel(x))
df.head()
```

And...voila!

```
     fuel  fuel_type
0     LPG          3
1  Petrol          2
2  Diesel          1
3  Diesel          1
4     CNG          4
```

#### Option 2

Another, very similar approach that doesn't require you to write a function is to simply map values in a dictionary:

```
values = {
    'Diesel':1,
    'Petrol':2,
    'LPG':3,
    'CNG':4
    }

df['fuel_type'] = df.fuel.apply(lambda x:values[x])
```

#### Option 3

To further simplify things you can accomplish the same without using `apply` - use `map()` instead:

```
df['fuel_type'] = df.fuel.map(values)
```